# unicode-math breaks \not command

Tags: xetex, luatex, unicode-math

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}

\begin{document}
$\not\propto$
\end{document}
```

Results in:

[image: result]

How can I solve this?

Comment: Yes, it's broken; in this case it uses `\mathchar"3236` which is of course the wrong thing to do, because it indeed simply prints a 6 considered as a relation symbol. On the other hand, Unicode defines no symbol that could take place of `\not`, as far as I can see; there is U+0338, but it doesn't behave, in my experiments.

Comment: unicode will *never* define a symbol that adequately takes the place of `\not`; the tex "dead key" approach does not fit the unicode model.  besides, the shape of the `\not` symbol is already inadequate in the tex model, as can be seen from the many `\nXXXX` symbols provided.  `\nprop` isn't one of them.  so this is best handled by defining such a composite and using that.

Answer (score 2):

`unicode-math` is already checking to see if `\npropto` is defined (it is not, in this case) and only falls back to overprinting if it is not defined. It uses the original definition (saved as `\__um_oldnot:`) which isn't really appropriate here, rather than redefine `\not` to do something else as a fallback, cheat a bit and redefine the saved `\__um_oldnot:` to overprint a `/`.

For any command where the negation combination doesn't look good, simply define `\n`*xxx* to do something else, the example below shows a default positioning and then the effect if you define `\npropto` to use a vertical stroke,

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\def\__um_oldnot:#1{\mathrel{%
\mathchoice
{\rlap{$\displaystyle\mkern1mu/$}}%
{\rlap{$\textstyle\mkern1mu/$}}%
{\rlap{$\scriptstyle/$}}%
{\rlap{$\scriptscriptstyle/$}}%
{#1}}}
\ExplSyntaxOff


\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}

\begin{document}

$a \not\propto b$


\newcommand\npropto{\mathrel{|\mkern-12mu\propto}}


$a \not\propto b$

\end{document}
```