# How to get a `not divides' symbol of the correct size using lualatex and unicode-math package?

Tags: luatex, unicode-math

I am having problems with `\not` command.  I have read this:
[unicode-math breaks \not command](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/267791/unicode-math-breaks-not-command)
I have tried the fix mentioned there.
This MWE compiles without problems in pdflatex:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\newcommand{\Mod}[1]{\ \left(\mathrm{mod}\ #1\right)}
\begin{document}
    
    \(p^{k+1}\nmid\left(\alpha^2-a\right)\)
     $p^{k+1}\not\left\vert\left(\alpha^2-a\right)\right.$
\end{document}
```

[image]

The first one with `\nmid` gives a small `divides' symbol So, I use` \not\left\vert ...\right.`to get a larger`divides' symbol. I get the desired output in pdflatex as seen in the screen shot above. So, there is no syntax problem.
But, this mwe gives problems in lualatex:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\def\__um_oldnot:#1{\mathrel{%
        \mathchoice
        {\rlap{$\displaystyle\mkern1mu/$}}%
        {\rlap{$\textstyle\mkern1mu/$}}%
        {\rlap{$\scriptstyle/$}}%
        {\rlap{$\scriptscriptstyle/$}}%
        {#1}}}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\setmathfont{XITS Math Regular}
\newcommand{\Mod}[1]{\ \left(\mathrm{mod}\ #1\right)}
\begin{document}
     \(p^{k+1}\nmid\left(\alpha^2-a\right)\)
     $p^{k+1}\not\left\vert\left(\alpha^2-a\right)\right.$
\end{document}
```

I get the following error message:

```
! Missing { inserted.
<to be read again> 
\left 
l.18     $p^{k+1}\not\left
                      \vert\left(\alpha^2-a\right)\right.$
A left brace was mandatory here, so I've put one in.
You might want to delete and/or insert some corrections
so that I will find a matching right brace soon.
If you're confused by all this, try typing `I}' now.

! Missing } inserted.
<inserted text> 
}
l.18 ...not\left\vert\left(\alpha^2-a\right)\right.$
                                                  
I've inserted something that you may have forgotten.
(See the <inserted text> above.)
With luck, this will get me unwedged. But if you
really didn't forget anything, try typing `2' now; then
my insertion and my current dilemma will both disappear.
```

How to fix this problem.

**Edit:** @egreg has pointed out that the pdflatex version works by accident of implementation. What is the best way to get a `not divides' symbol of the correct size that works with unicode-maths also?

Comment: This *cannot* work: `\left` needs to process everything up to the matching `\right` before TeX decides the size of the delimiter. You're misusing `\left` and `\right` anyway.

Comment: @egreg There is nothing wrong in the latex syntax. The expression compiles fine in pdflatex.  The problem is only with unicode-maths.

Comment: @egreg The first MWE compiles fine in pdflatex. Please check it out. I have also explained why I need the \left\vert ...\right. construction.

Comment: The first example *seems* to work with `pdflatex`.  But just by accident of implementation: in that context `\not` just prints a zero width character which extends past its (empty) bounding box.

Comment: @egreg I have modified the question. Please take a look when you are free.